# C# , receiving data from serial port using readto()

Tags: c#, serial-port

I have a device that sends data in format of `[stx]..data...[etx]`

Is there any way to use `serialport.readto()` function to read the data upto `[etx]` ?

```
byte test = sp.ReadByte();

if (test == 0x02 && comOpen)
{
   string indata = sp.ReadTo("");
   watch = "\n" + indata;
   SetText(watch);
   process_data(indata);
   sendack(0x06);
}
```

Data amount varies each time it sends the data.

I found the implementation of `serialport.read()` function very typical :). so is there any way that I can use `serialport.readto()` function to read data in the incoming stream?

Any suggestion would be very helpful.

Comment: It isn't clear at all why you are not using ReadTo() correctly.  Is the hangup that you don't know how to use it or is the hangup that the data is binary?

Comment: sp.Readto("") contains a character between "" parsed by a serial data logger for [ETX] . it does not show up here nor in the VS but its there. I am simulating the device from a simulator to develop a application to process this data.

Comment: Hmm, well, don't do that.  Use "\u0003" instead.

Comment: Hans Passant made my day. Greatly Appreciate .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got past this issue by using "\u0003" in sp.readto() function.

```
sp.readto("\u0003")
```

Answer (score 0):

If etx is of multiple bytes you will need to compare it with the buffer to know when you have received the end of the transmission.

Example:

```
// Set to whatever ending marker is used in your scenario.
var endingMarker = new byte[] { 0x01, 0x02, 0x03 };
var buffer = new List<byte>();

// Continue to read until ending marker is read.
while (!endingMarker.SequenceEqual(buffer.Skip(Math.Max(0, buffer.Count - endingMarker.Length))))
{
    // Read one byte to the buffer.
    buffer.Add(sp.ReadByte());
}

// Remove ending marker.
var result = buffer.Take(buffer.Count - endingMarker.Length).ToArray();
```